# Has VS2010 with SP1 intellisense changed autocomplete defaults?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2010

It appears that sometime after I installed VS2010 sp1 autocomplete now requires me to push the down arrow to select the object I'm typing.

For example the old behaviour was to just type the object name and press enter:
[image]

The new behavior is to press the down arrow and enter.  Screen shot of unselected item below (Possibly caused by VS2010 SP1 ):

[image]

This is so bothersome, and I checked tools: options but didn't see the correct option.  Does anyone know how to fix this *besides learning new tricks* ;)

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report beta bugs.

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Connect site for SP1: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=207109

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in [suggestion mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/22/intellisense-suggestion-mode-vstipedit0012.aspx).

Press Ctrl+Alt+Space to switch to standard autocompletion mode.

Comment: It makes sense for TDD, but I wish I had a warning before it was enabled!

Comment: Can you turn it off pernamently?

Comment: @Roman: It should be off by default.  You could change the shortcut key in options.

Comment: It shows automatically from time to time and I have to press Ctrl+Alt+Space every time to return back. I would like to get rid of it completely, but couldn't find anything in the settings.

Comment: @Roman: Clear the shortcut key for `Edit.ToggleCompletionMode` in Options.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not sure how is that supposed to help. I did it, the suggestion mode still sometimes appear and now I can't switch back. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Roman: How are you getting it to it? It won't toggle by itself.  There is a toolbar button, which you can click, then remove.

Comment: THANKS! this thing drove me crazy

Comment: @SLaks: Actually, it *does* toggle by itself. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exbffbc2.aspx) says: *In some IntelliSense scenarios, suggestion mode is used even if you do not enable it.*